# PreparedStatement execute() doesn't affect the database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I have issues when inserting data into a mysql database with jdbc.
when adding a new user to the database, I get a new connection, create a prepared statement and execute the query. However, no results are shown in the database.

For example, let's assume I manually add a new user in the database with MySql Query Browser.

- I add a new user --> name = Stefano, pin = 1010
- An auto-increment id is generated: id = 1.

Suppose I decide to add a new user programmaticaly:

- I call the method addUser(String username, int pin) --> addUser("pippo", 7636);
- No error occurs
- I open MySql Query Browser and none user is added.

Finally I add a new user manually:
name = pluto , pin = 3434.

Now my table result in:

| id | name | pin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | stefano | 1010 |
| 3 | pluto | 3434 |

`id=2` is missing. So `pippo` has been added but I can't see it.

What's wrong?

Here my java code simplified:

```
package simpleexample;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class SimpleExample {

public static void addUser(String username, int pin) {
    
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStmt = null;
    String insertSQL = "insert into users(name, pin) values (?, ?)";

    try {

        conn = DBConnectionPool.getConnection();

        preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertSQL);
        preparedStmt.setString(1, username);
        preparedStmt.setInt(2, pin);
        preparedStmt.execute();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SimpleExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            DBConnectionPool.releaseConnection(conn);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    addUser("pippo", 7636);
}
}
```

Here the class DBConnectionPool:

```
package simpleexample;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.*;

/**
  * This class simulates a db connection pool
  */
 public class DBConnectionPool {

/*
 * This code prepare the db connection pool. In particular, it creates the
 * free connections queue and defines the db properties.
 */
static {
    freeDbConnections = new ArrayList<Connection>();
    try {
        DBConnectionPool.loadDbProperties();
        DBConnectionPool.loadDbDriver();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("DB DRIVER NOT FOUND!");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("DB CONNECTION POOL ERROR!");
        System.exit(2);
    }
}

/**
 * The db properties (driver, url, login, and password)
 */
private static Properties dbProperties;

/**
 * The free connection queue
 */
private static List<Connection> freeDbConnections;

/**
 * Returns a free db connection accessing to the free db connection queue.
 * If the queue is empty a new db connection will be created.
 *
 * @return A db connection
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public static synchronized Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection connection;

    if (!freeDbConnections.isEmpty()) {
        // Extract a connection from the free db connection queue
        connection = freeDbConnections.get(0);
        DBConnectionPool.freeDbConnections.remove(0);

        try {
            // If the connection is not valid, a new connection will be
            // analyzed
            if (connection.isClosed()) {
                connection = DBConnectionPool.getConnection();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            connection = DBConnectionPool.getConnection();
        }
    } else // The free db connection queue is empty, so a new connection will
    // be created
    {
        connection = DBConnectionPool.createDBConnection();
    }

    return connection;
}

/**
 * Releases the connection represented by <code>pReleasedConnection</code>
 * parameter
 *
 * @param pReleasedConnection The db connection to release
 */
public static synchronized void releaseConnection(
        Connection pReleasedConnection) {

    // Add the connection to the free db connection queue
    DBConnectionPool.freeDbConnections.add(pReleasedConnection);
}

/**
 * Creates a new db connection
 *
 * @return A db connection
 * @throws SQLException
 */
private static Connection createDBConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection newConnection = null;

    // Create a new db connection using the db properties
    // newConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
    //    "jdbc:mysql://localhost/resources", "root", "");
    newConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            DBConnectionPool.dbProperties.getProperty("url"),
            DBConnectionPool.dbProperties.getProperty("username"),
            DBConnectionPool.dbProperties.getProperty("password"));

    newConnection.setAutoCommit(false);

    return newConnection;
}

private static void loadDbDriver() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName(DBConnectionPool.dbProperties.getProperty("driver"));
}

/**
 * Loads the db properties
 *
 * @throws IOException
 */
private static void loadDbProperties() throws IOException {
    InputStream fileProperties = new FileInputStream("database.properties");
    DBConnectionPool.dbProperties = new Properties();

    DBConnectionPool.dbProperties.load(fileProperties);
}

}
```

Note: I have a file Database.properties in the project with

- driver=org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
- url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/name_db
- username=root
- password='password'

I already used the DBConnectionPool class in other projects and it's always worked fine. So I don't understand what's wrong. Maybe something about transactions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You disable auto commit in your connection pool (seriously: don't roll your own, use an existing one, they will do a better job than this).

You never call commit anywhere in your code, therefor the result is never committed (and eventually when the connection really gets closed or otherwise lost, the change will get rolled back).

My advice:

1. Call `commit()` (or `rollback()`) when you have finished your unit of work.
2. Start using a real connection pool, like HikariCP, DBCP or c3p0

Comment: Yeah, you right: what a mistake!!!! Thank you, I really forget to commit the changes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use executeUpdate() not execute().

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)

> int executeUpdate(String sql)
>                     throws SQLException
>
> Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or
>   DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an
>   SQL DDL statement.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)

> > boolean execute(String sql)
> >                     throws SQLException
>
> The execute method executes an SQL statement and indicates the form of
>   the first result. You must then use the methods getResultSet or
>   getUpdateCount to retrieve the result, and getMoreResults to move to
>   any subsequent result(s).

Comment: Calling `execute` instead of `executeUpdate` will work (and I'm sure some JDBC implementations actually call their `execute` implementation from `executeUpdate`).

Comment: I tried with also with executeUpdate(), but the result is the same :/