# SQL script executed with Python doesn't affect the database

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have [`this SQL script`](https://github.com/LiveClub/FastAPI/blob/main/database.sql) that I want to use over a `MySQL 8.0` database.

```
-- Table for the users
CREATE TABLE users (
    id              INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, -- Unique ID for the record
    username        VARCHAR(42) NOT NULL,                 -- Name of the user
    tag             INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,                -- Tag of the user
    registered      DATE NOT NULL,                        -- Date of the sign-up to LiveClub
    PRIMARY KEY     (id)                                  -- Make the id the primary key
);


-- Table for the channels
CREATE TABLE channels (
    id              INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, -- Unique ID for the record
    messages        VARCHAR(10),                          -- Link to .json with list
    PRIMARY KEY     (id)
);


-- Table for the messages
CREATE TABLE messages (
    id              INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, -- Unique ID for the record
    channel_id      INT unsigned NOT NULL,                -- ID of the channel where the message is
    type_           VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,                  -- Type of the channel
    txt             VARCHAR(8000),                        -- Content of message (if txt message)
    -- img             IMAGE                                 -- Image (if img message)
    PRIMARY KEY     (id)
);
```

---

I want a `Python` script to execute it, so I tried installing some libraries to communicate with MySQL.

```
mysql                         0.0.3
mysql-connector               2.2.9
mysql-connector-python        8.0.29
mysqlclient                   2.1.0
```

This is the code I'm running in the same directory as the `.sql` file.

```
from mysql.connector.cursor import MySQLCursor
from mysql.connector import connection

c = connection.MySQLConnection(
    user='root', 
    password=open('mysql-password.txt').read(), 
    host='127.0.0.1', database='tentativo'
)
cursor: MySQLCursor = c.cursor()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("database.sql", "r") as file:
        cursor.execute(file.read(), multi=True)
```

After running the script above I went to `MySQL CLI 8.0`

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sakila             |
| sys                |
| tentativo          |
| world              |
+--------------------+
7 rows in set (0.19 sec)
```

The database, that I had created manually before, existed, but then looking into it...

```
mysql> use tentativo
Database changed

mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.03 sec)
```

I tried checking both during and after the Python execution, and the result was always the same.

---

I read some answers like the following:

- [data being inserted into MySQL but not made permanent - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477124/data-being-inserted-into-mysql-but-not-made-permanent-python)
- [PreparedStatement execute() doesn't affect the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276650/preparedstatement-execute-doesnt-affect-the-database)
- [How can I insert data into a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687718/how-can-i-insert-data-into-a-mysql-database)

They all were saying to insert that `connection.commit()`, I did it but nothing changed.

```
c.commit() # Added this two lines
c.close() # But the database was still unchanged
```

I hope somebody can help me, thanks in advance.

## Edit

---

Changed this way my Python script as suggested by `Xi Gou`.

```
c: connection.MySQLConnection = connect(
    user='root', 
    password=open('mysql-password.txt').read(),
    host='127.0.0.1', database='tentativo'
)
cursor: MySQLCursor = c.cursor()
```

Nothing changed in the behaviour, since `mysql.connector.connect` returns an initialized `sql.connector.connection.MySQLConnection` object which has the same argument as the other one I created manually.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an env now, but I guess the problem may be you got a connection.MySQLConnection object, but did not really open a TCP connection to the mysql server.

just follow the [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-ddl.html) and write code like this:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
```

to open a connection and execute sql.

Comment: Nice try but it didn't work  thank you anyway